# Machine Check error using Nvidia drivers on 15.04

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, cpu

Hwæt,

Hardware specs:
CPU: AMD FX 8350 8-core
GPU: Nvidia GeForce GT 630
Motherboard: ASUS M5A78L-M/USB3

A few weeks ago, under Trusty Tahr, I started having graphics problems.  Several bad solutions later, I ended up with a fresh Vivid installation.  With the passage of time, I am increasingly convinced it is a hardware problem (though I am still STRONGLY in denial).  Here is what happens:

1. Under nouveau graphics, machine works normally for a while before freezing up.  Can only be fixed via hard reset.  All other inputs nonresponsive.
2. Switching to nvidia drivers (have tried various versions suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/61433/409886)) results in crashes soon after log-in.  /var/log/syslog records:

   ```
   [Hardware Error]: System Fatal error.
   [Hardware Error]: CPU:0 (15:2:0) MC4_STATUS[Over|UE|MiscV|PCC|AddrV|-|-]: 0xfe00000000070f0f
   [Hardware Error]: MC4 Error Address: 0x000000fdfc000cfc
   [Hardware Error]: MC4 Error (node 0): Watchdog timeout due to lack of progress.
   [Hardware Error]: cache level: L3/GEN, mem/io: GEN, mem-tx: GEN, part-proc: GEN (timed out)
   ```
3. Have tried the nvidia drivers with the nomodeset option /opt/default/grub.

Again, this really seems like a bad CPU.  But the fact that the machine crashes differently with the nouveau drivers than with nvidia drivers gives me the merest glimmer of hope that I can save my wallet.

So, things I would like to know:

1. If this can be fixed purely by installing new packages or configuring others, the bards will sing your praises for generations to come.
2. If it is an irreparable hardware problem as I have feared, any additional diagnostic steps I can take to see which components are at fault: only the CPU, [perhaps the motherboard](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140152), or other parts.  I would like to save funds on any part which isn't causing problems, but also don't want to leave a faulty component sitting around.

Comment: I would suggest maybe the Hiren's Boot CD that is full of Open Source diagnostics and miscellaneous applications to help diagnose and repair a system.  http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/